# Can we programmatically create a iPhone AdHoc Network?

Tags: iphone, wifi, adhoc

Is it possible to create adhoc network programmatically in the iPhone, So that other device can connect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without jailbreaking it; no. If your phone is jailbroken and you want to know how to, Google has lots on it, but if that doesn't work out, update your question and be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

GameKit uses either Bluetooth or Bonjour (WiFi but not adhoc), so it is not WiFi adhoc network.

Answer (score 0):

You can not setup a standard WiFi adhoc network on the iPhone. However the GameKit allows for setting of peer-to-peer networks between iPhones.